# Using c# Method to execute SQL Query

Tags: c#, mysql

What is the best technique to run SQL query that then displays that information on a Winform textbox whilst avoiding repeat code? With My basic understanding of c#, I have created the below method but it requires me to add the same text twice at the end.

```
  public MySqlDataReader RunQueryTextField5(string query, Control c1, string s1, Control c2, string s2, Control c3, string s3, Control c4, string s4, Control c5, string s5)
    {
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;


        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();


        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            c1.Text = (myReader[s1].ToString());
            c2.Text = (myReader[s2].ToString());
            c3.Text = (myReader[s3].ToString());
            c4.Text = (myReader[s4].ToString());
            c5.Text = (myReader[s5].ToString());

        }

        conDataBase.Close();
        return myReader;
    }
```

// is how I call it if the other query but as you can see since this one only has four fields I pass on the last fields twice.

```
RunQueryTextField5("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `Course qualification Prices` WHERE `qualification name` = '" + cboQualificationName.Text + "' AND `delivery mode` = '" + cboTrainingDeliveryMode.Text + "' ",


                    txtTrainingQualifcationCode, "course unit code",
       txtTrainingQualificationPrice, "Price",
      txtTrainingMaterialsHyperLink, "Support Materials Hyperlink",
              txtTrainingMaterialsHyperLink, "Support Materials Hyperlink",
              txtTrainingMaterialsHyperLink, "Support Materials Hyperlink");


            }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of having the list of parameters as a hard-coded sequence of (Control, String), make the method accept a Dictionary of type Dictionary(Control, String). Then in the method you can loop over all the (key, value) pairs within the Dictionary and set the value for the controls (Working with Dictionaries in C# is pretty straightforward, reading associated MSDN docs will get you the required details). This way, you won't need to pass unnecessary or repeated parameters, thus avoiding repetition.

Comment: that looks like the answer I am looking for but just a little confused on how to implement it. So in the method, I would put the dictionary name instead of hardcoding all those values and when the button is clicked it assigned values to that dictionary? Any chance you could provide the code in my example?

Comment: Instead of the while loop, you can have a foreach loop over the keys of the dictionary, and then for each key you can do something like this:
key.Text = myReader[dict[key]].